# Align with three &

Tags: align

Consider

```
\begin{align}
  \text{the} \quad & \text{quick} \\
  \text{brown} \quad & \text{fox}
\end{align}


\begin{align}
  \text{jumps} \quad & \text{over} \quad & \text{the} \\
  \text{lazy} \quad &  \text{dog} \quad & \text{other words}
\end{align}
```

It yields

[image]

I would have expected (and would like) to have the space between "over" and "the", and also between "dog" and "other words" not to be so large, and to have "the" and "other words" to be aligned on the left (as "quick" and "fox"). How can I achieve this?

---

alignat seems quite good, but it produces on this other example

```
\begin{alignat}{4}\label{eq:state_equations}
  &\partial_t v -\Delta v&&=0  \quad \partial_t w -\Delta w&&=0 \quad &&\text{on }\Omega\times I \\ 
  &v &&= v_D \quad \partial_\nu w&&=w_N  \quad &&\text{on }\Sigma \\ 
  &v &&=0 \quad w &&= 0 \quad &&\text{on }\Sigma_0\\
  &v(0)&&=0 \quad w(0)&&=0  &&
\end{alignat}
```

a weird output. I would like "v" to be close to "v_D" for instance.

[image]

Any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, `align` alternates right aligned and then left aligned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you're probably looking for `alignat`, and adding some alignment points `&` to adjust the alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \text{jumps} \quad & \text{over} \quad & \text{the} \\
  \text{lazy} \quad &  \text{dog} \quad & \text{other words}
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \text{jumps} \quad & \text{over} \quad && \text{the} \\
  \text{lazy} \quad &  \text{dog} \quad && \text{other words}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

---

For the specific example in your question, here's the correct notation using `alignat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
  \partial_t v - \Delta v &= 0         & \partial_t w - \Delta w & = 0         && \text{on }\Omega \times I \\ 
                        v &= v_D \quad &          \partial_\nu w & = w_N \quad && \text{on }\Sigma          \\ 
                        v &= 0         &                       w & = 0         && \text{on }\Sigma_0        \\
                     v(0) &= 0         &                    w(0) & = 0
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```